# Хитрый sql запрос для одной таблицы

Tags: postgresql, sql

Помогите составить sql-запрос.

Есть табличка:

```
    equipment    | cstate
-----------------+--------
 10.10.11.6      | up
 10.10.11.6      | up
 10.10.11.6      | up
 10.10.11.6      | up
 10.10.11.6      | down
 10.10.11.6      | down
 10.10.11.10     | up
 10.10.11.10     | up
 10.10.11.10     | up
 10.10.11.16     | down
 10.10.11.16     | down
 10.10.11.16     | down
 10.10.11.16     | up
 10.10.11.16     | up
```

Нужно привести к виду

```
    equipment    | up | down | total
-----------------+----+------+------
```

Где up всего портов с статусом  up, down - всего c статусом down и totol - всего портов up + down.

Буду весьма признателен.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select equipment, 
       sum((cstate = 'up')::int) as up, 
       sum((cstate = 'down')::int) as down, 
       count(*) as total 
    from tbl group by equipment;
```

Comment: я как раза сам уже решил 

SELECT  equipment,
        COUNT(*) as total,
        SUM(CASE cstate WHEN 'up' THEN 1 END) AS up,
        SUM(CASE cstate WHEN 'down' THEN 1 END) AS down
FROM    port
GROUP BY
  equipment
ORDER BY 
  equipment

но все равно спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Решение не только для PG:

```
select equipment , 
    sum(case state when 'up' then 1 else 0 end) AS "up",
    sum(case state when 'down' then 1 else 0 end) AS "down",
    count(*) as "total"
    group by equipment
```

Comment: а что если сделать `select` из `select`'a, как вы думаете `execution plan` будет хуже?

Comment: Я с постгресом почти не работаю. Зависит от оптимизатора. Сравните планы.

Answer (score 2):

Для PostgreSQL >= 9.4 реализован более читаемый синтаксис из SQL:2003

```
select equipment, 
   count(*) filter(where cstate = 'on') as up, 
   count(*) filter(where cstate = 'off') as down, 
   count(*) as total 
from tablename group by equipment;
```